# Mean in the normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I am learning about normal distribution and I have this exercise:

> If X is a random variable of normal distribution with mean equal to
>   zero, then all its values They are equal? True or false

My attempt:

The mean,median and mode coincide in the normal distribution. So, if the mean $= 0$, then median, mode $=0$, and also the range of the values ​​that a random variable with a normal distribution can take, are: $]0, \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}]$ and since the only value for which the mean is $0$ and all the values ​​are equal, is $0$, but the zero is not within the range, therefore it is false.

I want to know if my development is correct or it has only been a coincidence. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The statement is false (with probability $1$ except in the degenerate case where the standard deviation is $0$, in which case I would call it a single valued distribution rather than a normal distribution).  A random variable with a normal distribution can take any real value and the probability that any two samples of it give the identical value is $0$

Comment: So my development is bad? And can you please explain more in an answer please?,

Comment: basically u say that the values of x cant be equal because the random variable will be only a one point?

Comment: No - I am saying the values will be almost certainly be different (except in a special case which I do not think counts) because this is a continuous random variable which can take any real value

Comment: So, in reality, the statement has nothing to do with probability, but, in the line of the reals, all the values ​​are different?

Comment: Is true that if the mean is = k, then the median and mode is k too? can you please help me with this doubt

Comment: For a normal distribution the population mean, median and mode are all the same (though not for a sample from a normal distribution).  This is not the case for many other distributions such as an exponential distribution

Comment: Thanks for answer that doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh???  Why would you ever think that?

[image]

Comment: Confusion of concepts, thanks for the graphic!